# Design Idea for an inventory analytics tool design

Tags: apache-spark, database-design, analytics, dask, parquet

I am designing a tool for inventory transactions analytics using Python, with pandas and Out of core tools. There will be some big data here (2gb to 200gb), so I'm using Dask.

My table have `SKU, STORE, DATE_BY_DAY, SOLD_PRICE, ORDER_VOLUME, INVENTORY_LEVEL.` 
I'm using the parquet format, partitioned by store (the partitions would get too small if I partition it by sku).

I wanna have fast queries with very low latency (mostly just some aggregations and filters by SKUs and store). The problem is I have to do it **all on the fly.**
Besides that, I have to calculate the inventory level (`INVENTORY_LEVEL`) for each day based on the current inventory (that's on another table), also reindex by the date, because there might be some missing days on the source file.

Dask doesn't support multi-indexing and the sorting is very expensive, so it gets too hard and slow to do the computations mentioned above.

My options and ideas so far:

1. Move entirely to Spark. (I'm currently Using dask)
2. Move to a row-oriented format. (I'm currently Using Parquet)
3. Change the table schema somehow, like creating one table for the `SOLD_PRICE` and another one for the `ORDER_VOLUME`, both indexed by `SKU, STORE` with the date pivoted as columns.
4. Create an concatenation of SKU and Store to reduce the indexing hierarchy.

Which of these options could bring performance enhancement to my project? Can you suggest something else?

Answer (score 1):

> There will be some big data here (2gb to 200gb)

200 GB isn't big data, but I will say "2 to 200" is 2 orders of magnitude, not much of an estimate.

> Can you suggest something else?

Yes: SQL.  I have yet to see Pandas outperform SQLite, much less a full-blown SQL DBMS, and the larger the dataset, the better SQL will do. SQL will also give you a more expressive, more comprehensive syntax, and relieve you of some of the tedium of Pandas.

SQL was invented for "on the fly" queries, by the way.

I would suggest loading your data into SQLite.  At a guess, it looks like you have only one or two tables.  Then try a few queries and see how you do.  Don't overlook indexes for your favorite search and join criteria.  I think you may be pleasantly surprised at how quickly it computes, say, `inventory level`, and with how little effort on your part.

It's not as if you have to give up Python.  There are two Python libraries for SQLite, one of which is used with most SQL engines.  You keep Python for the UI work, and let SQL crunch the data.